# How do I setup different environments for a given solution in IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, environment

I have a solution on IBM Cloud that includes a front-end app and multiple microservices. All are Cloud Foundry apps.

I need to establish multiple environments (dev, test, demo, production) for my solution. So that I can for example, create a stable demo build of all components that is independent of the components in my dev environment.

How do I create separate environments in IBM Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this through dedicated cloud foundry space and resource group(IAM enabled services). Here is a solution tutorial with step-by-step instructions explaining exactly what you are looking for -  [Plan, create and update deployment environments](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-plan-create-update-deployments)

Additionally, you can also check the [Best practices for organizing users, teams, applications](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-users-teams-applications)